# pass javascript var to php with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, php

I'm setting up a website that runs a countdown timer (10 min to zero). When pressed "start timer", timer goes of. when pressed "reset", timer goes back to 10 min and the last measured time is saved in een database and used in php. but going from javascript to php isn't working. (New in this, both php en javascript are in the same file)

Calling the database is no problem, its sending new data to the database that is a problem
i'm trying to pass the var with window.location.href, but it prints notting out. I tried to use cookies but that also failed (poor skills).

```
-----------alle in the file timer.php--------
<?php
//random code
function php_getJavascript(){
                if(!empty($_GET['waarde'])){
                        echo $_GET['waarde'];
                }
        }
//random code
?>
<html>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <body>
        <div id="control">

            <button onclick="startTimer()">Start timer</button>
            <button onclick="resetTimer()">Reset</button>
            <button onclick="printLogs()">PrintLogs</button>

        </div>
        <div id="timer"></div>
<script>
            var endTime = 0;
            var tijd = new String("10:00");
                setText('10:00');

//random code
            function resetTimer() {
                setText('10:00');
                window.location.href='timer.php?waarde='+tijd;
                endTime=0
            }
            function printLogs() {
                var print = "<php php_getJavascript();?>";
                //var print = "<?php php_printFunc();?>";
                setText(print);
            }
//random code
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

output database (pre-set data to see if database works):

```
id-1-Datum-2019-05-06 17:03:48-Tijd-9m50s
id-2-Datum-2019-05-06 17:03:55-Tijd-9m38s
id-3-Datum-2019-05-06 17:04:02-Tijd-6m44s
id-4-Datum-2019-05-06 17:04:21-Tijd-6m59s
id-5-Datum-2019-05-06 17:04:25-Tijd-1m59s
```

but when trying to send data to php
this is what i get on my url when de timer stops running:

```
https://192.168.7.2/timer.php?waarde=9:57
```

but when i want to print from php, it prints notting

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted, it appears the `php_getJavascript` function isn't called when you load the page. So, your data wouldn't be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, you should be able to pass the data to `setText` by changing `printLogs` to something like this:

```
function printLogs() {
    var print = <?php echo json_encode($_GET['waarde']) ?>;
    setText(print);
}
```

You should also remove the `php_getJavascript` function, it doesn't do what you intend - it outputs bare data from the request, which will cause a syntax error in most cases, it's also not safe in case you want to publish the code somewhere.

If that doesn't help, you can debug this problem by viewing the page source (CTRL+U) or using the developer tools (F12). This way you should be able to see how what you do in JavaScript affects PHP and vice versa.

Comment: but if I do that, how can I use <?php echo json_encode($_GET['waarde']) ?>; in php? Do you add another var in php to use that var? I don't really see the usage of your method? Security is no big deal, it is for a project from school.